# TransactionScope/SqlTransaction timeout extension

Tags: .net, sql-server, transactions, transactionscope, sqltransaction

Is it possible to extend the timeout of a transaction (with SQL Server) once the transaction has started?

Comment: Not AFAIK... and in many cases it would be up to DTC, not the SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timeout is "external" to SQL Server, so SQL Server can not affect it.

So "no" unfortunately

Comment: Just out of interest, in what way is it external? When I said "with SQL Server" I meant that is the database I'm using, not that the transaction needed to be extended using SQL.

Comment: Ah, I mean that the timeout is set by the caller or msdtc, and is not known to SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it, but you could rollback and retry.